# How to get Fee Payer of a transaction? from TransactionResponse object

Tags: web3js, solana, solana-web3js

I am trying to make a small public script to fetch the initial minter of a token or a list of tokens.

The easiest way is to fetch the transaction that matches with the correct program id and get the fee payer because, in 99.99% of the cases, the fee payer is the minter itself.

I am trying to get the fee payer from a [TransactionResponse](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#TransactionResponse) object.

I can see that `transaction.transaction.message.accountKeys[0]` gives the fee payer but I couldn't find any resource to verify that the first account in [`accountKeys`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Message.html#accountKeys) array is always the fee payer.

Is this way safe? If not, is there any other convenient way to fetch the fee payer of a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payer is always the first account referenced, and the first signature is by the fee payer.

Here's a reference in the message code:

```
In the `Message` structure, the first account is always the fee-payer,
```

Excerpted from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/c419845cfeb1c7ab9ca959de66e90b9dacbc25b7/sdk/program/src/message/legacy.rs#L90

You can follow along the (slightly complicated) logic in JS: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/c419845cfeb1c7ab9ca959de66e90b9dacbc25b7/web3.js/src/transaction.ts#L415